Parsing string to datetime using pandas
I am trying to parse a string to datetime using pandas but I am getting the following error:
ValueError: Cannot parse both %Z and %z

My date string is:
ds = '03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 GMT+0100'

and the conversion I'm trying is as follow:
format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z%z'
dt = pd.to_datetime(ds, format=format)

which is funny because panda seems to use an almost identical version of strptime. When I use:
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(ds, format)

it works as expected. In the pandas documentation there is a small section saying "Differences to strptime" but no mention to usage of %Z with %z.
On further explanations about timezones and offsets I only see explanations regarding UTC offsets. In this case I assume that GMT and UTC is anyways the same so if I parse using:
format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f GMT%z'
dt = pd.to_datetime(ds, format=format)

this also works. But I was wondering, what if one has a datetime with offset regarding to a different timezone, for example EST instead of UTC? For example:
ds = '03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 EST+0100'

is there anyway one could convert this directly using pd.to_datetime()?

here's what i got: ds = '03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 GMT+0100'
pd.to_datetime(ds)
Timestamp('2021-03-01 23:00:00+0100', tz='UTC+01:00')
do you need the format ?

%z is "UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]" ... so EST+0100 doesn't make any sense.

GMT is sometimes used as a synonym for UTC, so GMT+1 is just UTC+1. I'd remove the "GMT" and parse with %z. Or just let pd.to_datetime do its thing without providing a format! But please set dayfirst=True in your case.

GMT+0100 is not really a standard format. Usually you only have +0100 and the reference is UTC.
What you could do is extract the offset and add it after conversion to Timedelta:
import re

ds = '03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 GMT+0100'

m = re.search(r'(.*)(\+\d+)$', ds)
H, M = divmod(int(m.group(2)), 100) # + 1h0min

fmt = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'
dt = pd.to_datetime(m.group(1), format=fmt) + pd.Timedelta(60*H+M, unit='min')

Output: Timestamp('2021-01-04 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
Output for 03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 EST+0100: Timestamp('2021-01-04 00:00:00-0500', tz='UTC-05:00')
vectorized approach
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 GMT+0100',
                            '03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 EST+0100']})

tmp = df['date'].str.split(r'(?=\+)', expand=True)
H, M = tmp[1].astype(int).divmod(100)

fmt = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'
df['out'] = (pd.to_datetime(tmp[0], format=fmt, utc=True)
            +pd.to_timedelta(60*H+M, unit='min')
            )

Output:
                               date                       out
0  03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 GMT+0100 2021-01-04 00:00:00+00:00
1  03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 EST+0100 2021-01-04 05:00:00+00:00


pd.to_datetime("03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 GMT+0100", dayfirst=True) works fine for me. If you ever encounter serious data that has EST+0100 as a UTC offset, please send it to me. This is worth to be part of a talk "how to shoot yourself in the foot with timezones" :)

@FObersteiner I agree EST+0100 is non-standard/weird/risky, thus my initial comment. pd.to_datetime('03.01.2021 23:00:00.000 EST+0100', dayfirst=True) wouldn't work however.

@FObersteiner I wanted to avoid the discussion if the EST+0100 is common or not but rather the programming issue, how the pandas function could deal with a format string that would understand that the offset is not in relation to UTC but to another known timezone, without doing the manual parsing/conversion before calling the function. Apparently it is not possible, but it's fine anyways..
